# What is right method to pass activationData from app to Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-provisioning, applepay, apple-wallet

I am trying to integrate Apple Pay In-App provisioning into bank application. My question is about the activationData parameter that returns from our host and must be passed to Wallet. Should an activationData be passed through addPaymentPassViewController delegate method only,  or it is necessary to call activate(_:activationData:completion:) method as well? If it is necessary, what is the right place where I should call this method?

Comment: Did you manage to find out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@daviddvd19/inapp-provisioning-enrolling-cards-en-5c368591d320

Maybe this link could be useful for you. I followed these steps for integration. The only question is how to create this activations data in BE side, I was not able to find step by step documentation in Apple website.